# Changing color in ticks google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

__Hello, guys. I'm practicing in google charts. And I met a problem, which I can't to solve.
[google chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUSU2.png)

I'm using ticks labels:

> 'vAxis': {
> ticks: [{ v: 720, f: '12:00' }

And want to customize colors for two values in tick label:

```
data.addRow(
        ['{{list[i][0]}}',
        { v: {{list[i][1][0]}}, f: '{{list[i][1][1]}} {**color: #335408**}Yest: + {{list[i][2]}}' }]
```

How can I do this?

Upd1:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css">
  <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script>
    
    // var list = {{ list|safe }}
   google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['', 'May'],
     ['', 0]
   ]);
    
    {% for i in range(list|length) %}
        data.addRow(
            ['{{list[i][0]}}',
            { v: {{list[i][1][0]}}, f: '{{list[i][1][1]}}' + '\n' + 'Yest: +{{list[i][2]}}' }]
            );
    {% endfor %}
   
    var options = {
     title: 'Current month',
     hAxis: {title: ''},
     vAxis: {title: 'H:Min'},
     width: 1080,
     
     'vAxis': {
        ticks: [{ v: 720, f: '12:00' }, { v: 1440, f: '24:00' }, { v: 2160, f: '36:00' }, { v: 2880, f: '48:00' }, { v: 3600, f: '60:00'}, { v: 4320, f: '72:00'}, { v: 5040, f: '84:00'}, { v: 5760, f: '96:00'}, { v: 6480, f: '108:00'}, { v: 7200, f: '120:00'}, { v: 7920, f: '132:00'}]
    }
    };
      
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('oil'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
   }
```

Comment: Please share the full code of your chart and with some sample data in the chart.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I did it now.

Comment: check this answer --> [Customize hAxis ticks colors in Google Bar Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51155333/5090771)